# Error during loading data frames (xlsx Format) in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loading

Good afternoon,

I’m currently working in R and importing data sets that have .xlsx format.

I use standard function read_excel.

For example:

MCC_1 <- read_excel("MCC_1.xlsx", guess_max = 500000, n_max = 500000)

Most of my files were imported correctly, however suddenly I faced with an error.

It is said: Error: expected ' or "

In a Traceback section I see this:

class = c("rapidxml::parse_error", "C++Error", "error", "condition")

Could you give me any ideas or even solutions of how to overcome it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution by myself!

All you have to do is to create a copy of your excel file to a new file. The problem stated appears when R is trying to read .xlsx files that were made automatically - for example during data unloading procedure from specific databases.